# How to merge 4 different pdf files into a single A4 size sheet using R or python?

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pdf, merge

Is there a way to merge 4 PDF files into one sheet (single page) with R or python?  So from 4 different PDF files to a single page containing all 4. The layout would be like that of the image shown below. I do't want to do this using command line. I need a code which would do this everyday.